# after upgrading to 4.8 from 3.0.3 Lucene Net performance issue

Tags: lucene.net

after migrating from 3.0.3 to 4.8, indexing new document is slower than 3.0.3

but index file size much smaller than 3.0.3.

here my code

```
private IndexReader reader;
private IndexSearcher searcher;

var writeconfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, analyzer);

    writer = new IndexWriter(_directory, writeconfig);

    foreach (var member in list_of_members)
    {

    new_(writer, member.name,member.surname, member.location); 

    }
    writer.Dispose();
    reader = DirectoryReader.Open(index_location);

    searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    public void new_(Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter writer, string name, string surname, string location)
    {


        Document doc = new Document();

        doc.Add(new StringField("name", name, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.Add(new TextField("surname", surname, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.Add(new StringField("location", location, Field.Store.YES));

        writer.AddDocument(doc);

            }
```

when comparing with 3.0.3 indexing new document almost 2x slower than 4.8..

edit 1: found out the performance problem with field compression;

found the this webiste about  performance of stored field compression  [field compression](https://stegard.net/2015/05/performance-of-stored-field-compression-in-lucene-4-1/)

at web site they explain disabling compressing in java but couldnt convert the code into c#...

now my question is , how can i disable field compression with lucene.net 4.8?

Comment: What is your question? You have only stated your problem so far.

Comment: why is 4.8 slower than 3.0.3? new version should be faster than old version?

Comment: As for altering the codec (which is what they do in the article you refer to)... Keep en mind that .NET uses properties over Setters/Getters, as such the equiv of cfg.setCodec(...) would be cfg.Codec = ... Which seems to be perfectly possible... I can't say if they have ported all Codec's yet though, so you might have to do that your self...

Comment: @fuujinnn the answer didn't fix your problem?

Answer (score 3):

seems like this is compression issue, after version 41, fields store are compressed by default.
in this case, compression penalty is too high.

add no compression codec:

```
 public class NoCompressionCodec : FilterCodec
 {
        internal NoCompressionCodec(Codec @delegate) : base(@delegate)
        {
        }
        public override StoredFieldsFormat StoredFieldsFormat => new Lucene40StoredFieldsFormat();
 }
```

override the default codec factory

```
public class CustomCodecFactory : DefaultCodecFactory
{
    private readonly NoCompressionCodec _noCompressionCodec;
    public CustomCodecFactory()
    {
        _noCompressionCodec = new NoCompressionCodec(Codec.Default);
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        PutCodecType(typeof(NoCompressionCodec));
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override Codec GetCodec(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(NoCompressionCodec))
            return _noCompressionCodec;

        return base.GetCodec(type);
    }
}
```

and run this on your startup

```
Codec.SetCodecFactory(new CustomCodecFactory());
```

on your index writer, set codec to:

```
indexWriterConfig.Codec = new NoCompressionCodec(Codec.Default);
```

Comment: Interestingly enough this helped us even when using a `RAMDirectory` thanks for the tip quite a drop when utilizing a `MultiFieldQueryParser` from an average of 13 requests per second to 49. Big thank you to the Author.

Comment: I implemented your code, but what gets setup is the default which is now Lucene46, but you were saying it should be prior to 41.